# Replace a string into numeric value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I need help with the codes below:

First I do this:

```
medias = []
for col in dataset_1:
    medias.append(dataset_1[col][~(dataset_1[col] == '?')].median())
```

After i tried to replace "?" for the median:

```
for col in dataset_1:
    for media in medias:
        dataset_1[col].replace('?', media)
```

But didn't work! What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not reassigning back to the column.

Comment: Read the documentation.  `in_place=False`  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet you're modifying the `dataset_1`'s column with `Pandas.DataFrame.replace` method which by default returns the modified DataFrame instead of changing it in place. In order to fix your problem you either have to reassign the DataFrame column with the modified one or set `in_place=True` in the method call.

Reassigning the returned column:

```
for col in dataset_1:
    for media in medias:
        dataset_1[col] = dataset_1[col].replace('?', media)
```

Modify in place:

```
for col in dataset_1:
    for media in medias:
        dataset_1[col].replace('?', media, in_place=True)
```

PS. If I had to be honest I'm not sure what you want to achieve by this code as if you replace all of your `?` in the first iteration you don't need to go through all of the medias because there'll be no `?` anymore (except for the case when `medias` itself contains `?` then it's understandable).